# How to instantiate global variables by executing a text file lines within a Python3 function?

Tags: python-3.x, function, scope

I want to use a Python function to instantiate the variable `my_var` to a default value.
Next, I want to use the following `input.txt` text file to modify the value of `my_var`:

```
my_var = 0.15 # Change the value
print(f"In the text file, my_var={my_var}")
my_var = 0.15; print(f"In the same line, my_var={my_var}")
```

Here is the Python script that reads the lines in the text file and executes them one by one:

```
def run_exec():
    my_var = 1.0 # Default value
    f = open("input.txt")
    lines = f.readlines()
    for l in lines:
        exec(l)
    print(f"Within the function, my_var={my_var}")
    return my_var

my_var = run_exec()
print(f"Outside the function, my_var={my_var}")
```

When running this script in my terminal, I get:

```
At the beginning, my_var=1.0
In the text file, my_var=1.0
In the same line, my_var=0.15
Within the function, my_var=1.0
Outside the function, my_var=1.0
```

It looks like each executed text line comes with its own scope... How can I get `my_var=0.15` outside the function?

Comment: Surely there are better ways to get values from a text file into a variable then using `exec`. What exactly are you hoping to accomplish? This seems like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/357835).

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks for your answer.
I am looking for a way to read input parameters provided by a user in a text file. I would like to have a function which takes the text file path and returns my variable with the adequate value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the code run by each invocation of [`exec()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) runs in its own scope. It's not possible to directly affect the local variables of a function in `exec()`, but you can pass a dictionary to `exec()` to use as a container for new local variables created within the function:

```
def run_exec():
    local_dict = {}        # container for local variables in exec()
    my_var = 1.0   # Default value
    with open("input.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            exec(line, globals(), local_dict)

    # local variable unchanged
    print(f"Within the function, {my_var=}")

    my_var = local_dict.get('my_var', my_var)    # defaults to my_var
    print(f"Within the function {my_var=} after explicit assignment")
    return my_var

my_var = run_exec()
print(f"Outside the function, my_var={my_var}")
```

**Output**

```
In the text file, my_var=0.15
In the same line, my_var=0.15
Within the function, my_var=1.0
Within the function my_var=0.15 after explicit assignment
Outside the function, my_var=0.15
```

Of course, you should never do this because it is extremely dangerous to execute untrusted code, for example if the file contained this:

```
exec('import os; os.remove("some_important_file")')
```

Besides that, there are better ways to do this such as config files,  import a module with the required variables, JSON files etc.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I will use a JSON config file instead, it seems safer indeed. Best

Comment: As I suspected, this was an XY problem. You did a nice job of addressing both X and Y.